# Retrieve Data from another server via Jquery Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, same-origin-policy

I want to retrieve some data from another server via ajax. I have searched through the net and been advised to use jsonp method. My question is if that other server does not returns data in json format rather than plainText then how can i catch that data, is there any way?

Comment: What is the data structure used by the server ? are you using a web-service ? can you show us what have you tried ?

Comment: server is just echoing a string and i am trying from my local server(wamp)...

Answer (score 1):

If the server doesn't allow cross-origin resource sharing, and doesn't implement JSONP, you need to use a local proxy. Try the [Simple PHP Proxy](http://benalman.com/projects/php-simple-proxy/).