# $ajax always call error handler

Tags: jquery

I would like to create a simple "is an url active" validation.

Here is what I have so far:

```
function checkUrl(url) {
    var ok = false;
    $.ajax(
        {
            url: 'http://www.google.com',
            success: function(result) {
                ok = true;
            },
            error: function(result) {
                ok = false;
            },
            async: false
        }
    );
    return ok;
}
```

But it always return false. Note the 'www.google.com' url is there for testing purpose only.

Comment: even the same problem I am also getting

Comment: This is because of Cross-Domain AJAX restrictions.

Comment: Because you have a cross domain exception. See : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: Did you bother to look at the error message?

Comment: @Barmar how to remove it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieve Data from another server via Jquery Ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15173567/retrieve-data-from-another-server-via-jquery-ajax)

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal See the question I just linked to.

Comment: Aaah, I see. Is there any other option how to test a cross-domain site whether is active?

Comment: You need to create a proxy like http://isitup.org/ It is a server side process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of what is called [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), it is a security policy implemented by browsers which prevents cross-domain ajax calls.

A solution to this is to use a [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), but the server to which you want to connect must support this policy.

[jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) supports jsonp.

Ex:

```
$.getJSON('<resource-url?callback=?>').done(function(data){
    //Your callback logic
});
```

Comment: When JSONP is supported, it's usually just for APIs, not random URLs. So this is not likely to be useful for a general purpose "Is URL alive" test.

Comment: Yes, but it's not a general solution right? I need to validate any url user puts in form.

Comment: yes. in that case you may have to write a server side piece which can use a http-client library to check whether the url exists

Answer (score 0):

Try This :-

```
function buildQuery() {
            return "select * from json where url = 'google.com'";
        }

        $.ajax({
           url: 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql',
           data: {
               q: buildQuery(),
               format: "json"
           },
           dataType: "jsonp",
           success: function (result) {
               alert("Success :" +JSON.stringify(result));
           },
           error: function (result) {
               alert("error: " + JSON.stringify(result));
           },
       }
   );
```